# Blank page before large print

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I'm trying to print a Google Chart that's about 12 pages long. It displays great in all web browsers (there is nothing above the chart), however when I print the document, it will print a blank page or two above the chart.

Is there a CSS or JS or any other type of fix for this? My chart is currently using:

```
position: static;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

Comment: Try not using any position static.
Try using position relative.
If still problems persistes then tell us which type of Graph you are using?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart <- this style barchart with hundreds of entries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is no longer reproducible (it was solved with a patch over 5 years ago), the only answer did not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using any position static. Try using position relative. If still problems persistes then tell us which type of Graph you are using?

Try using https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1047436

Printing your chart

To print your charts, you can either save it as an image or download your spreadsheet as a PDF document. Here's how:

Follow these steps to save your chart as an image:

```
Click your chart to show the grey frame around it.
Click the chart menu in the upper left of the frame.
From the chart menu, select Save Image.
Open your saved image from your downloads folder.
```

Alternatively, you can download your spreadsheet as a PDF. This will include your chart, as well as the data in your spreadsheet.

```
From the File menu of your spreadsheet, select Download as > PDF.
Specify the customization options you'd like for your PDF, such as the selection you'd like to print and the layout of the page you print to.
Click Export, and a PDF file containing your spreadsheet will be downloaded.
```

Once you've saved your image or downloaded it as a PDF, you'll be able to print your chart using Ctrl + P on a PC or Cmd + P on a Mac.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart <- this style barchart with hundreds of entries. Changing position did not make a difference.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot or a public link to the page?

Comment: And what happens when you Print -> Save as PDF?

Comment: It contains sensitive data and there's no good way to screenshot it, sorry. The printing options aren't available with the charts I was using, I ended up copying the contents of the div to a new window w/ jQuery and adding a print button there and it seemed to work. It's a hack but it's late and I don't care anymore. Will accept your answer for the replies. Thanks.